# Is there any article or paper that describes what Thomas Sargent thinks of New Keynesian economics/models?

Tags: macroeconomics, academic-graduate, new-keynesian-economics

Is there any article or paper that describes what Thomas Sargent thinks of New Keynesian economics/models?

I am asking this question, because we all know what Thomas Sargent thinks of Old Keynesian economics, but I can't find what he thinks of New Keynesians that involve sticky price (well, Calvo/Rotemberg/etc. methods) and imperfect competition.

Answer (score 4):

This journal article (Oct 29-2011,) has parts from a telephone conversation of the journalist with Sargent:

http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/30/your-money/thomas-sargent-nobel-winner-rejects-philosophical-slogans.html

Although none of it mentions "New-Keynsian", there are some interesting points, like

> *"Professor Sargent said he felt insulted by people who call him
>   “non-Keynesian” or “right wing,” terms that, he said, are based on a
>   misunderstanding of his thinking... He’s a Democrat, he said, “a fiscally conservative, socially liberal Democrat,” adding, “I
>   think that budget constraints are really central.”"*

On Keynes?

> *"The “non-Keynesian” label irks him particularly. “That’s just off
>   base,” he said. “Keynes was a very good economist. He was brilliant.
>   He had wonderful insights. His work has inspired me many times.”*"

So are we to believe that Sargent is a "Keynesian"?

> *"Today, Professor Sargent says that in some ways he actually is a
>   Keynesian, but he qualified that claim, too. “I’m happy to say I am a
>   Harrison-Kreps-Keynesian,” he said, citing work by two scholars at
>   Stanford, J. Michael Harrison and David M. Kreps. They developed a
>   theory of speculative investor behavior and stock-bubble formation
>   that subtly modifies rational expectations “in a beautiful way” and
>   “captures Keynes’s argument, makes it rigorous, and pushes it
>   further,” he said."*